# how show specific text view in list view depending on position item kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I am new in [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) and I've built a simple app which shows flights Scheduled via `JSON` data. I've used `ListView` and everything is working fine. but I want to add `TextView` in my `ListView`. For example, when user scroll down `ListView` the `TextView` I want to show depending on position I wanted in `ListView`.

For example this `ListView` shows date in middle of `ListView`

[image]

So can l choice which position the element I want to show in `ListView` depending on the position?

For example after item position 36 I show the element which I want .

```
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 36
}
```

My code for `ListAdapter`

```
class ListAdapteDep (val context: MainActivity, val list: ArrayList<FlightShdu>): BaseAdapter() {
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "NewApi")
    override fun getView(p0: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dep_list,parent,false)
        val list = list[p0]
        val LogoAriline = view.findViewById(R.id.logo_image) as ImageView
        val status = view.findViewById(R.id.status_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val Airport = view.findViewById(R.id.airportid) as AppCompatTextView
        val code = view.findViewById(R.id.code_id) as AppCompatTextView
        val TimeFlight = view.findViewById(R.id.time_id) as AppCompatTextView
        view.callsign_id.text=list.Callsign
        view.airline_id.text=list.Airline
        code.text = list.code
        view.status_id.text=list.Stauts
        status.text= list.Stauts
        TimeFlight.text = getDateTime(list.TimeFlight)


        Airport.text= list.Airport
        view.model_id.text=list.Model

        //the text view l want to show depending on postion l want in item count

        val date = view.findViewById(R.id.time_id) as AppCompatTextView

        date.text = getDateTime(list.date)




        return view
    }

    private fun getDateTime(s: String): String? {
        try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm a")
            val netDate = Date(s.toLong() * 1000)
            return sdf.format(netDate)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return e.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return list [p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 36
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can check for the position in `getView` method, then you can render view dynamically according to the current position

Comment: like this ?        `if (p0 == 25){
            Airport.setText("test")

        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the position in `getView` method, then you can render view dynamically according to the current position.